# system call to kill a process inside linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I have begun with kernel programming and I would like to kill a task group. I want to know which system call to use.

I have already got the current->tgid and current->pid  but how do I kell the process inside the kernel??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to kill the task group that `current` is a member of, then simply call `do_group_exit(exit_code)`.

Comment: @user489152: No, `sys_kill()` is not correct to use from inside the kernel itself.  No code in the upstream kernel does this.

Comment: Ok. Just another clarification. How about kill_pgrp()?

Comment: Btw i am doing changes in net/ directory

Comment: @user900785: `kill_pgrp()` is for signalling a job control process group, which is not the same thing as a task group.

Comment: Ok I guess I have some issues. I have an application which has spawns a number of threads. At one point I want to kill this application. So I get its tgid. This is also the pid of that application as I can see from "ps" command. So now in order to kill the entire Application with all its threads, should I not do an equivalent of kill(current->tgid) inside the kernel? When I tried do_group_exit(SIGKILL), I see some other (perhaps related) processes disappearing... Could you explain?

Comment: @user900785: Do you want to kill `current`, or some other process? `do_group_exit()` will do the former.  TGIDs / PIDs should *not* be used to identify tasks *within* the kernel, they are for communication between userspace and the kernel.